# How to detect which files are switched to a different branch in my working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm in a situation where some sub-folders and/or files of my working copy are switched to a different branch version.

Is there a way, without brute-force deleting everything and checking out again (some of these switches may be legit!), to know the source of all folders and files to notice which ones are from an unexpected branch?

Additional difficulty: I'm on Windows. I'm fine with a Tortoise or command line solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Check for modifications` from TortoiseSVN context menu. If file/folder was switched then the `Switched-Flag` is set to `1`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I never noticed these stats before... and I *just* understood what were these extra "normal (s)" lines: switched items. Seems like all I needed to do to "clean up" the WC was Switch to the expected branch from the root again.

Comment: What did you mean with "and I just understood what were these extra "normal (s)" lines: switched items."? Was my answer the solution for you respectively help you to find a solution?

Comment: Well, I assume the line under your black bar should have a status of "normal (s)" since it lists one switched item. I somehow ended up with dozens of items in that state in my working copy and didn't "get" what they were until your answer. In a sense, you answered my question on multiple levels :)

Comment: ;-). The file was not in the list until I switch the branch of the file. After switch it hat the shownstate.